# How to use a manually installed .NET SDK in Polyglot Notebook

Tags: visual-studio-code, polyglot, dotnet-interactive

I am trying to use Polyglot Notebooks in VS Code. I am on a corporate computer that only has Dotnet SDK 5.0 installed, and I do not have admin privileges. I have downloaded the binaries for the most recent version of .NET 7 and unzipped them into a selected location. I have updated my user environment variables to include this in DOTNET_ROOT and the PATH variables and have modified my VS Code settings.json file for all applicable settings. In VS Code, when I run dotnet --version in the terminal, it shows as 7.0.202.
Similarly, when I run F# script files, it uses 7.0.202. However, when I try to use Polyglot Notebooks, I get the ".NET 7 SDK REQUIRED" message. Is it possible to get Polyglot Notebooks to reference this manually installed Dotnet SDK? If so, how can I accomplish this?